# NFS-Root not working when booting over PXE

Tags: nfs, debian-squeeze, pxe-boot, tftp, initramfs

I am desperately trying to get a diskless client running over PXE-Boot using a NFS-Share as a root file system. I did this before some years ago but for some reason I am stucked at this since days.

The TFTP-Server itself is running fine and booting a netinstaller works also fine. The kernel and initrd are loaded also but the bootprocess stops with [this (screenshot)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57649457/kernel-panic.png) kernel panic.

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57649457/kernel-panic.png]

I'm using the squeeze standard i386-Kernel and I have prepared the initrd with this config:

```
MODULES=most
BUSYBOX=y
KEYMAP=n
COMPRESS=gzip
BOOT=nfs
DEVICE=
NFSROOT=auto
```

I also tried

```
MODULES=netboot
```

with the same outcome.

My PXE-configuration looks like this:

```
LABEL linux
KERNEL diskless/debian-default/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686
APPEND root=/dev/nfs initrd=diskless/debian-default/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686 nfsroot=192.168.140.2:/storage/nfs-boot-images/default-squeeze ip=dhcp rw
```

Furthermore I have captured the network communication of the client via tcpdump and learned that the client isn't even trying to connect to the NFS-share.

Does anybody has got an idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is wrong;

> initrd=diskless/debian-default/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686

you are trying to load as initrd what in fact is the KERNEL; see the kernel line.
That's why when the kernel tries to mount a kernel copy as the initial ram disk it panics...
correct that line and you'll be fine

Comment: Thank you very much! That did the trick. Seems as if I was blind on both eyes ...